# How do I add a SAR file to a Monticello repository?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I am now developing in Squeak.

I want to add a .sar file (archived squeak file) to Squeak Repositories, so other developers can access the .sar file from Monticello browser.
I know there are several repositories like [trunk](http://source.squeak.org/trunk/), [inbox](http://source.squeak.org/inbox/).

How can I upload a .sar file to the repository as a package or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. SAR-files are not compatible with Monticello repositories.

- Monticello repositories are used to version packages during development.
- SAR-files are used to bundle different kinds of code artifacts in one bundle for distribution.

SAR-files used to be very popular when SqueakMap was on the raise. I haven't seen new SAR-files in the past couple of years. We stopped to produce SAR builds for Seaside, Magritte and Pier many years ago.